# B2 Visitor visa - Surnames are different in my passport and dad's passport

Tags: usa, passports, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I am from India and I am working in the USA on H1B VISA. I want to apply B2
(visitor) visa for my parents but I have a situation ( as below) where I
need your inputs.

All my father's documents have different last name "ABC" (his mother's
maiden name) than his original surname(which is not there on any of his
documents). Whereas his original surname "XYZ" is carried into all my
documents including my passport.

Recently my parents got their passports. Since the documents required for
applying passport are carrying his official last name(my father's mom's
maiden name), my dad got his official surname "ABC" on his passport. So now
the last name for my dad is different in his passport and my passport.

No issue with my mom's passport though. Her last name and my last name (
i.e., my dad's actual surname) are same in our passports.

Can you please let me know :

1. If it is an issue for my parents' visitor visa because my surname is
   different from my dad's in the passports?
2. What are the corrective measures to be taken to overcome this problem?
3. Also, my passport is about to expire in two more months from now. Will
   it be an issue at the time of visa interview for my parents' visitor visa
   ???

Comment: There are plenty of families where not every member has the same surname. Why is this a concern?

Comment: Question 3: Your passport expiration shouldn't affect your parents visa application, but it will affect *you,* do you should probably apply for a new one as soon as you can. The other questions: the fact that you're his son is probably not that important. They could just as well be visiting some random acquaintance. So they're probably not going to look for grounds to doubt your claimed relationship.

Comment: Do you have some other document proving your relationship, such as a birth certificate?

Comment: @200_success Thanks for your reply. This is a concern for me because my father's last name in my passport is "ABC" and in his passport his last name is "XYZ" which is completely different.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for your reply. In I134 form, I will be stating the relationship to the person I am sponsoring the visa for. Having said that , my father's last name in my passport does not match with the last name in his passport . That's where I am stuck at

Comment: @JonathanReez Thanks for your reply. Even in birth certificate I have my father's last name as "ABC" which does not match with his last name in his passport

Comment: @Meera do you have any evidence to connect your father's names to the same person?  *His* birth certificate, perhaps?

Comment: @phoog He does not have his birth certificate. We are planning to apply for it now. However, I believe he gets his last name same as the one that is being carried in all his other documents

Comment: I am in a same boat, Did your parents got their VISA? how did you manage that?

Answer (score 2):

> So now the last name for my dad is different in his passport and my passport.

This was not a problem when I was applying, I doubt it has changed since then.

There are plenty of colorful family name combinations. For example, in my family I am the only one that has my father's *first name* as my last name - all my siblings have my father's last name as their last name.

No problems getting B1/B2/F1 visas for my family members.