# Will difference in surname of applicant and guardian lead to visa refusal?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I am from India. I am planning to study in US. I have my father's last name as "ABC" in my passport as well as all other documents but my last name is "xyz". But again in all his official documents, his last name is "xyz". Will this be a problem while issuing visa? What are the solutions to this problem?

Comment: Although your question is off-topic, [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71001/b2-visitor-visa-surnames-are-different-in-my-passport-and-dads-passport) is useful reading

Comment: Why is your father's name in your passport?  Or is it your name, too?

Comment: Why do you have a different surname for your father on your documents to what he has?